# Is there a way to prevent notepad from inserting new lines when using word wrap?

Tags: windows-7, windows, text-editing, notepad

I remember it wasn't doing this before but now when I am writing a few paragraphs and paste it into a forum post, I notice my lines were broken into new lines where I have to merge them manually.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? I just want to see my text visible within the size of my notepad without horizontal scrollbars, but not have the text modified according to this.

Comment: That is not the default behavior. Try to disable word wrap, then re-enable it. What if you change the size of the window after you type it up, do more line breaks appear?

Comment: Actually when I resize more lines do appear which I never seen before. I will try disabling and reenabling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**:

Save the document and then re-open it in Notepad.

**Explanation**:

The carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) are created with a new line in Windows text files, and both characters are needed to make text files compatible with old dot-matrix printers that had to be told to feed the paper. The CRLF has created all kinds of problems because sometimes these two invisible characters get unjoined.

Since XP, Notepad sometimes adds an extra CR when the editor is in wordwrap mode and the document is saved; wherever the line wraps, a CR is put in. This creates a new line in the editor, which you can see when you change the client's size or edit existing lines. However, this problem is *only* visual, and the document is not saved with the extra CR.

To solve the problem, simply save the document then re-open it in Notepad and it should look fine.

One last note: this is not merely a painting problem but a problem with the text in the buffer, so copying the text to another editor does not solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is not only visual, since as you said the extra line breaks are copied if you try to copy the text you typed in notepad into an online post or something.  I cannot believe this bug has persisted since Windows XP, is still present in Windows 7... it's been there for like 15 years now.  This bug needs an award, and Microsoft needs smacked.

Comment: Still present in Windows 10 too. Never noticed it in Windows 7.